# the macro \micro in siunitx does not work with fontspec

Tags: fontspec, siunitx

In recent versions of `siunitx` the macros `\si{\micro}` and `\SI{0.550}{\micro\m}` do not work with the package `fontspec`.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
wavelength $\lambda =$ \SI{0.550}{\micro\m}\\

wavelength $\lambda = \SI{0.550}{\micro\m}$\\

It should be wavelength $\lambda =  0.550 \,\mu \text{m}$.

\end{document}
```

Do I have to set any option in `siunitx` or `fontspec`?

Comment: And what fonts are stating in the preamble to use with `fontspec`?

Comment: Good title of this thread: macro micro :).

Comment: expecting two members of the LaTeX3 team to make their packages work together, amazing optimism:-)

Answer (score 8):

This is an issue introduced in v2.6a to try to improve font coverage for some package combinations. For the present, use

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument {
  \cs_undefine:N \c__siunitx_micro_int
  \int_const:Nn \c__siunitx_micro_int { "000B5 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

A fix will be sent to CTAN today.

Comment: @PeterGrill Sorted!

Comment: Adding the suggested code shows the mu letter but it also removes all space between words.

Comment: @user56595: The  solution has been revised snce then...

Comment: Another thing I notice with v2.6a is that the units with greek letters and some symbols do not appear if I use no-math option with fontspec. Everything worked fine with \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} before the last few versions of siunitx.

Comment: @user56595 I've revised the internals slightly to try to cover better the 'common cases' for `fontspec`/`unicode-math`. I can test if a package is loaded but not what options are set: the docs do say that particularly with the modern engines you might need to adjust things in terms of the symbols. It's not possible to detect every font set up, I'm afraid, so I have to try to pick what seems most likely. I'll see if I can work out a few more combinations automatically.

Comment: @user56595 For v2.6 I've switched the standard setting to typeset the unit part of a quantity in math mode, which is much as you'd do by hand: `\mathrm{m}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}` and so on. However, when you have `no-math` with `fontspec` you don't get the 'engine native' symbols as you do with the standard settings. So you'll need `\sisetup{unit-mode = text}` for that case.

Comment: @JosephWright \sisetup{unit-mode = text} works perfectly with fontspec with no-math option. I can even use math mode in the unit which is inside math mode, e.g.,     The mass of the particle is $m = \SI{2.4}{\MeV\per $c$^2}$.

Comment: @Joseph Wright When is the fix available on CTAN? I tried it a minute ago and the `\mu` is only shown with `\sisetup{unit-mode = text}`. Thanks!

Comment: @Dirk I've just checked this with the latest release (v2.6c) and with the example as given in the question all is fine. If it's not working, please e-mail me a demo.

Comment: Where do I find your mail address? This is a MWE, where only the volt symbol is shown.

    % Magic comments for TeXstudio
    % !TeX program = lualatex
    \documentclass{scrartcl}

    \usepackage{eulervm}
    \usepackage{siunitx, fontspec}

    \begin{document}
    \si{\micro\volt}
    \end{document}

Comment: @JosephWright I use `siunitx` version 2.6c and `fontspec` version 2.4a.

Comment: @Dirk E-mail address (joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk) is in the `siunitx` manual, on my website, _etc._ On your example, I can't pick up every font combination: there are simply too many. You are using a 'classical' virtual font with `fontspec`, which is tricky to auto-detect. I'd note that even without `fontspec` you need to do manual adjustment here: the combination is wrong. As I said, I do warn in the manual that it's not possible to get every combination of font packages 'right'.